# AngularJs Ng-Modal - Enable scroll bar

Tags: angularjs

I'm using AngularJs and ngModal plugin (https://github.com/adamalbrecht/ngModal) in my project. When the Modal is shown, it disables the browser scroll bar. How do I enable it in the instance it is shown?

My html code is below:

**html**

```
<body ng-controller="MyMgtCtrl">
    <div class="container-fluid" >
        <div class="section">{{gapSection.headerID}}.{{gapSection.sectionID}}</div>
        <label ng-click="showMenu()" class="label label-primary">Toggle</label>

        <modal-dialog show='data.showMenu' class="showMenuStyle">
          <p>SOMETHING GOES HERE</p>
        </modal-dialog>

    </div><!-- /.container -->

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the ng-modal plugin there was a property:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.overflow = "hidden"
```

I set to "hidden" to "" and the scroll bars were present